# Configurable JS component for a HTML Control

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am new to OO javascript. I want to make a dropdown button component which I can use anywhere in HTML. I have created a code for creating DOM. What I want to know is how to make properties configurable in that JS.

For example:

```
$('<div/>', {
    id:'btnDropdown',
    'class': 'btn-group pull-right',
    'role':'group',
}).appendTo('#settingPanel');           

$('<button/>', {
    id:'btn-default',
    'type': 'button',
    'class':'btn btn-default dropdown-toggle',                  
    'data-toggle': 'dropdown',
    'aria-expanded':'false'
}).html('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></span>').appendTo('#btnDropdown');

$('<ul/>', {
    'class': 'dropdown-menu',
    'role':'menu',
}).appendTo('#listCont');
```

Now I want the user to be able to configure the `id` where he wants to attach this component using desired `id` on HTML. Similarly icon location.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working code as a javascript component:

```
(function() {

    var defaults = { class: 'btn-group', role: 'group' };

    this.Dropdown = function (el, config, dropDownElement, content) {
        this.el = el instanceof $ ? el : $(el);
        this.dropdownElt = dropDownElement || '<div>';
        this.content = content || '';
        this.config = $.extend({}, defaults, config);
        this.createDropdown();
    };

    Dropdown.prototype.createDropdown = function () {
        var dropdownElement = $(this.dropdownElt, this.config).html(this.content);
        this.el.append(dropdownElement);
    };
}());

var config = {  id:'btnDropdown',
                'class': 'btn-group pull-right',
                'role':'group',
             };
var dropdown = new Dropdown ('#settingPanel', config); 

var newConfig = {
    id:'btn-default',
    'type': 'button',
    'class':'btn btn-default dropdown-toggle',                  
    'data-toggle': 'dropdown',
    'aria-expanded':'false'
};
var content = '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></span>';
var btnDropdown = new Dropdown ('#btnDropdown', config, '<button>', content);
```

Here is the jsFiddle, if you want to see it work:
https://jsfiddle.net/024vwbo3/3/

To configure the id now would be fairly simple as you just have to obtain those from the html as required and pass it to the configuration when creating a dropdown.